# New Feature Request: Add test data / sample scripts to questions/answers?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to add test data to questions and comments in this forum like in the arcgis and other forums? I have previously done this via services like google docs -but it would be easier if it can be done within gis.stackexchange.com itself.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks...didn't know it existed. will link it.

Comment: The same question was asked on a [sister site](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/uploading-data-to-site) and was declined.

Comment: To bad -maybe they should look at working with one of the file hosting sites so that we can simply click a link like "add data" and then enter our openid/similar credentials and add the files so that it autolinks into the stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

I think adding a link to your own dropbox site, or other, would be a good start.  I think there are several issues regarding data being passed into the site, IP, Copyright, etc, which would be a bugger to handle.  I am guessing it's best if we were left to police that ourselves.